# Blank page after submit

Tags: php

I've been busy creating a login script, only problem is i get a blank page after submitting the login form. I'm using a Template System.

Some codes,

login.tpl:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-login" action="/customer/login/submit" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-login-heading">$site_name Customer Panel</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="loginusername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
                <input type="password" name="loginpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block" type="submit" name="login">Log in</button>
                <center>
                    <div class="registration">
                        Don't got an account yet?
                        <a class="" href="$site_url/customer/register">
                            Create an account
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Submit.php:

```
    <?php
if (!isset($_POST['loginusername'], $_POST['loginpassword']))
{
    Site::Stop('/customer/login');
}

$Error = Users::Login($_POST['loginusername'], $_POST['loginpassword']);

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    Site::Stop('/customer/dashboard');
}

$_SESSION['login_error'] = $Error;
Site::Stop('/customer/login');

?>
```

login.php:

```
 $this->Define('LoginError', '');

if (isset($_SESSION['login_error']))
{
    $errors = Array(
        1 => 'This username does not exist.',
        2 => 'Your password is incorrect.');

    if ($_SESSION['login_error'] == 3)
    {
        $errors[3] = '  Your '.$_SESSION['ban']['bantype'].' is banned. 
                Reason: '.$_SESSION['ban']['reason'].'. 
                Your ban expires on: '.date('d-m-y H:i:s', $_SESSION['ban']['expire']);

        unset($_SESSION['ban']);
    }

    $this->Define('LoginError', '<div class="well well-danger">'.$errors[$_SESSION['login_error']].'</div>');
    unset($_SESSION['login_error']);

}

$this->LoadTpl('Login');
```

Maps.php

```
    <?php
$this->Map('/customer/login', 'Login.php');
$this->Map('/customer/register', 'Register.php');
$this->Map('/customer/register/submit', 'RegSubmit.php');

if (Users::$Session === false)
{
    $this->Map('/customer/login/submit', 'Submit.php');
}
else
{
    $this->Map('/customer/logout', 'Logout.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Blank page can mean syntax errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to catch and display.

Comment: It shows me this:  `Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/solustech/domains/solustech.nl/public_html/Solus/Library/MySql.php on line 40

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /home/solustech/domains/solustech.nl/public_html/Solus/Library/MySql.php on line 59

Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object in /home/solustech/domains/solustech.nl/public_html/Solus/Library/MySql.php on line 60`code``

Comment: that's a database / syntax error (or class related) and the code you posted in your question doesn't support it. Make sure the session was also started in all pages using sessions. Someone gave you an answer about it below.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure session has started with session_start() on top of php file.